# How do you write genotypic and phenotypic ratios?

Tags: human-biology, genetics

If two homozygous recessive parents are crossed, I know that all of the offspring will be homozygous recessive as well. Would you write the genotypic ratio as 0:0:4 then and the phenotypic as 0:4? (Does order matter? i.e. compared to 4:0)
Also, if the results are 2 homozygous dominant and 2 heterozygous, is it necessary to put the zero for recessive (2:2:0) or would 2:2 be fine?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is formal notation for those ratios.

One would note that perfect dominance and recessivity, perfectly discrete phenotypes without pleiotropy and without environmental variance is extremely rare and these examples are pretty much only encountered in intro classes but never in the real life. There is hence, for the phenotypes at least, really no need for any formal notation here.

That being said, out of clarity, I would definitely prefer 0:0:4 (genotypes) and 0:4 (phenotypes) over 4 (for either genotype or phenotype) and I would definitely prefer 2:2:0 over 2:2